# Issue when create new file in Xcode with Sierra?

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra

I have just install Sierra. Then when create new file in Xcode then happen bellow:[image]

Can not understand why happening lilke this. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Is this with Xcode 8.2 or an earlier version?

Comment: I am using Xcode 7. Also this happen in Xcode 8.

Comment: This also happens for me on macOS 10.12.2 with Xcode 7.3.1 but not with Xcode 8.2.